# how to fix The following assertion was thrown during layout: I/flutter ( 9632): A RenderFlex overflowed by 77 pixels on the bottom. I/flutter ( 9632):

Tags: flutter, terminal, flutter-layout

I am getting this error when I try to open a screen in flutter

```
The overflowing RenderFlex has an orientation of Axis.vertical.
I/flutter ( 9632): The edge of the RenderFlex that is overflowing has been marked in the rendering with a yellow and
I/flutter ( 9632): black striped pattern. This is usually caused by the contents being too big for the RenderFlex.
I/flutter ( 9632): Consider applying a flex factor (e.g. using an Expanded widget) to force the children of the
I/flutter ( 9632): RenderFlex to fit within the available space instead of being sized to their natural size.
I/flutter ( 9632): This is considered an error condition because it indicates that there is content that cannot be
I/flutter ( 9632): seen. If the content is legitimately bigger than the available space, consider clipping it with a
I/flutter ( 9632): ClipRect widget before putting it in the flex, or using a scrollable container rather than a Flex,
I/flutter ( 9632): like a ListView.
I/flutter ( 9632): The specific RenderFlex in question is: RenderFlex#86692 relayoutBoundary=up6 OVERFLOWING:
I/flutter ( 9632):   needs compositing
I/flutter ( 9632):   creator: Column ← _FormScope ← WillPopScope ← Form ← Center ← DecoratedBox ← Container ←
I/flutter ( 9632):     _BodyBuilder ← MediaQuery ← LayoutId-[<_ScaffoldSlot.body>] ← CustomMultiChildLayout ←
I/flutter ( 9632):     AnimatedBuilder ← ⋯
I/flutter ( 9632):   parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0) (can use size)
I/flutter ( 9632):   constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=411.4, 0.0<=h<=435.4)
I/flutter ( 9632):   size: Size(411.4, 435.4)
I/flutter ( 9632):   direction: vertical
I/flutter ( 9632):   mainAxisAlignment: start
I/flutter ( 9632):   mainAxisSize: min
I/flutter ( 9632):   crossAxisAlignment: center
I/flutter ( 9632):   verticalDirection: down
I/flutter ( 9632): ◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤
I/flutter ( 9632): ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

Here is my code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class Authform extends StatefulWidget {
  @override

  _AuthformState createState() => _AuthformState();
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
  }
}

class _AuthformState extends State<Authform> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey <FormState> ();
  var _isLogin = true;
  var _userCivilID = '';
  var _userName = '';
  var _userNationality = '';
  var _userEmail = '';
  var _userPassword = '';
  void _trySumbit() {
   final isValid = _formKey.currentState.validate();
   FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
   if (isValid)
     {
       _formKey.currentState.save();
       print(_userEmail);
       print(_userPassword);
     }
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(

      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage("images/bk.jpg"),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,

          ),

        ),




        child: Center(

            child: Form(child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget> [

            ListTile(
            title: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(child: RaisedButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  child: Text("Civilian"),
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
                side: BorderSide(color: Colors.black),
              ),
                ),
                ),
        Expanded(child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {},

          child: Text("Police"),
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
              side: BorderSide(color: Colors.black),
        ),),
        ),],
      ),
    ),
                   Container( child: Card(
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(45.0),
              side: BorderSide(color: Colors.black)),
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(40),

            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),

                child: Form(
                  key: _formKey,
                  child: Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: <Widget> [


                    if(!_isLogin)
                    TextFormField(
                      key: ValueKey ('Name'),
                      validator: (value) {
                        if (value.isEmpty )
                        {
                          return 'Please enter your name';
                        }
                        return null;
                      },
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.name,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'Name',
                      ),
                      onSaved: (value) {
                        _userName = value;
                      },
                    ),


                    if(!_isLogin)
                    TextFormField(
                      key: ValueKey ('Civil ID'),
                      validator: (value) {
                        if (value.isEmpty )
                        {
                          return 'Please enter a valid Civil ID';
                        }
                        return null;
                      },
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'Civil ID',
                      ),
                      onSaved: (value) {
                        _userCivilID = value;
                      },
                    ),

                    TextFormField(
                      key: ValueKey ('Email'),
                      validator: (value) {
                        if (value.isEmpty || !value.contains('@'))
                          {
                            return 'Please enter a valid email address';
                          }
                        return null;
                      },
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'Email Address',
                      ),
                      onSaved: (value) {
                        _userEmail = value;
                      },
                    ),
                    TextFormField(
                      key: ValueKey ('password'),
                      validator: (value) {
                        if (value.isEmpty || value.length < 7)
                        {
                          return 'Password must be at least 7 characters long';
                        }
                        return null;
                      },
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          labelText: 'Password'

                      ),
                      obscureText: true,
                      onSaved: (value) {
                        _userPassword = value;
                      },
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 12),
                    RaisedButton(
                      child: Text (_isLogin ? 'Login' : 'Sign up'),
                      onPressed: _trySumbit,
                    ),
                    FlatButton( child: Text ( _isLogin ?'Create new account' : 'I already have an account'),
                      onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        _isLogin = !_isLogin;
                      });
                      },
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
                      side: BorderSide(color: Colors.black)
                    ),)
                  ],
                ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),

        ),
        /* add child content here */


    //)
       ],

    ),
            ),
        ),

      ),

    );

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your whole wiget `child: Center` with `SingleChildScrollView` and remove the other SingleChildScrollView